# Non-locking sleep/waitfor/delay function for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am writing an ASP.NET class that interfaces with an external application. The flow of the transaction between the web server and this application is as follows:

1. My object writes a file to a directory.
2. The outside application detects this file and processes it. This can take between 1-5 seconds.
3. The outside application writes a response file to the same directory.
4. My object detects the response file and parses the results.

The 1-5 seconds it can take for the external application to process my file is my problem. The most straightforward way to wait for the file seems to be something like this:

```
Do While Not File.Exists(f)
    Thread.Sleep(500)
Loop
```

Of course, Thread.Sleep() completely locks up the rest of my website until the outside application processes the file. Clearly, this is not a workable solution.

How can I effectively "wait" for my file to be processed without locking up the rest of my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) - when a file will be created it will fire an event that you can subscribe to.

Comment: I've tried FileSystemWatcher, but the page load completes before the event fires. It seems this type of solution is better suited for functionality at the application level, but won't work in my situation.

Comment: My background is primarily in web development, and spinning up threads is a bit over my head. A cursory Google search has only served to further confuse me. Can you perhaps provide a simple code example, or a link to an explanation on how to use threading in this context?

Comment: I think I understand, but I don't think this accomplishes what I want it to do. Spinning a new thread means that the page load completes, and I then have to have the web page reload again and again, checking whether the thread is complete. Since all I'm doing is waiting for a file to be created, I can do that without threading, really.

For simplicity's sake, I'd rather keep this within the context of a single page load, but I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible without locking up the entire site. Thoughts?

Comment: @dansays - Even without threading, only the requests that caused the long running process should block. So long as the server has enough worker processes and threads available to it the site should still work.

Comment: Employing the Thread.Sleep(500) technique mentioned in my post locks up my development machine cold. Am I running into an artificial limitation imposed on non-Server instances of IIS7?

Comment: Exploring my IIS configuration, I came across a setting to change the number of worker threads in my application pool. Increasing the number of threads worked! Surely there must be consequences to this. Otherwise, why would the default number of threads be set to "1"?

Comment: @dansays - I don't believe it is. Looking at the Visual Studio template, it is not set there. Someone in your team must have done this.